# Vue native, NativeScript Vue - do they allow custom components?

Tags: react-native, nativescript, vue-native

I'm researching modern cross platform mobile frameworks. Currently i'm focused on frameworks that allow to use Vue (its awesome!).

As far as understand Vue native (React native is depth) and NativeScript Vue have some predefined components that will be transformed into corresponding native ui components for iOS or Android. The set of this components is limited.

I would like to know is it possible to add new custom components or reuse vue components or sub frameworks like vuetify? If yes, do you know examples or documentation about how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nativescript-vue yes you can create your own custom components just like you normally do with Vue.js, and about frameworks there are a bunch of plugins here

> https://market.nativescript.org/

Such that it is rare to not find what you need , feel free to join the slack channel as well

> https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/ssb/signin_redirect

And NO there is no support for DOM targetted frameworks like vuetify

Comment: Ok, so i cannot utilize "classic" vue components? Only construct components from already predefined?